# Changing text when clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, text

I have set up an event Listener and I want it so that when I click, the text in the middle changes from "Bubble" to "Bounce".

[whole code:](https://jsfiddle.net/0yx4ca98/2/)

```js
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Bubble";
document.addEventListener("click", next);

function next() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Bounce"
}
```

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #1F69FA;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section h2 {
  font-size: 10em;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: consolas;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2 id="text"></h2>
</section>
```

Comment: You found how to set the text "Bubble". What is different doing it in the event listener?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette because when I do it like this for example ` <h2 id="text2"> </h2> document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = "Bounce"; ` then the Bubble text gets pushed to the side as the h2 is essentially a placeholder there but I want it so that the two words dont interfere with eachother

Comment: The `section` has `display: flex;`, so for sure, if you add a second element, the first will move a bit. If you want the second word under the first, try `flex-direction: column;` -- Post your best attempt and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: Well in the Snippet it does work very well but in the whole code Im creating a canvas after the click and when I implement this line of code it either crashes because of "Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')" or it just doesn't show up at all.

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML = "";` squarely removes all elements inside the `body`. That is why.

Comment: So i have tried around a bit but my current problem is that when I leave out the `document.body.innerHTML = "";` then it does change to Bounce but my function after that to create the bouncy balls won't work. And if I just delete the head then I obviously still get the text but without the css applied. So I need to find a way to delete all elements of the page but still keep my h2 and partially some of my css elements. Do tou know any way to do that or would you go about this a completely different way?

Comment: Try just hiding the `section` with `document.querySelector("section").style.display = "none"`.

Comment: [new code](https://jsfiddle.net/wvc0m6os/3/) So I can hide it now but now the problem is, that the eventhandler for the next() function doesnt work and another problem I have is even if I make it a `document.addEventListener` and after switching screens or functions for that matter the Text "Bounce" still doesn't appear.